# can I write a method that will initialize a new image on the GUI and add spacing – swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, methods, swiftui

I'm trying to design a program that will allow users to click a button, take a picture, and have this image appear next to the button they just pressed so they can continue to add images to the GUI. I'm currently working through implementing the code to give the user access to the camera and photo library. However, I'm trying to figure out how I can go about storing the images on the GUI. Is it possible for me to write a method (func) that will instantiate a new image on the GUI and store the picture they selected in its place? I'd like to have a square "add photo" button that is in the center of the screen that allows the user to access the camera or photo library and upon choosing a photo, the image they select appears on the GUI, adjacent to the "Add photo" button, and that is the same size as the square "Add photo" button. What is the best way to go about this? Is it possible to call a method that will allow the user to keep taking pictures and retain spacing each time so that the user can store images in a 3x3 structure of images? Sorry if my description is confusing, please let me know if I can provide any further explanation - I'm new to SwiftUI so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Something like this that would create a new image on the GUI when it is called:

```
func createImage() {
    Image(systemName: "gear")
}
```

So it starts out with the first image, and then each time you click the button and select an image, it lays it out adjacent to the "Add photo" button like how these pluses are structured in the second image.

| First image | Second image | Third image |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Large plus icon in center of screen] | [image: 3x3 grid of plus icons, each smaller] | [image: App Layout upon opening] |

Comment: What do you mean by "adjacent to the "Add photo" button"? Should the new image go on the right, or something?

Comment: And also "retain spacing each time so that the user can store images in a 3x3 structure of images" - so you want the initial layout to already be a 3x3 grid (Not a single large plus icon, like in the first image)? And gradually fill in each placeholder with an image as the user adds images? Just clarifying.

Comment: if possible, id like the first screen the user sees to be the image I've uploaded with a single plus icon. then, after they've selected an image, the image would appear as a square image on the GUI - the same size as the plus icon, to its right, and the plus icon would still be there. So you would have two congruent squares - the plus icon and the image you selected. Then, the user could click the plus icon again to add another image, which would then appear to the right of the other image and so on until there is a 3x3 grid like what I've demonstrated in the second uploaded image.

Comment: I'm trying to allow the user to take a bunch of pictures and have the images appear on the GUI and allow the user to scroll through them. Kind of like apps on the home screen of the iPhone - but with the added ability to be able to scroll through them, (if this is possible and makes sense).

Comment: @aheze ^ thank you for any advice. still stuck

Comment: Np. What happens when you add the 4th plus icon though? Will it be added to the bottom and aligned left? And what happens if you add more than 9?

Comment: I'm hoping that when you add images they will appear in this 3 columned structure (the most recent image will always be to the right of the plus icon) and yes after adding the fourth image, the first one you took will be added below it and aligned left. I would love to allow the user to add up to ~75 images and, if possible, give the capability to scroll through all these images and remove images they no longer want in the collection. I want this to be like an image randomizer. I want these squares to show the pictures you've taken and id like them to be stored on the GUI.  @aheze

Comment: @aheze I added an image of the GUI I'd like to present when you open the app. I'd like the shuffle and settings button to remain in place and have the images appear below in the 3x75 structure I described and have the user be able to scroll through the images they add to this collection and have them stack on top of each other in a way that the user can scroll through fluidly (not sure if this is possible with swift but plz lmk).

Comment: @aheze lmk if this makes sense and is possible to program in swift. thank you

Comment: Yep, makes sense and definitely possible. Sorry for responding so late. I'll give it a go when I have time, but in the meantime, you can try to get some help in the [Discord Server](https://discord.gg/A9M2Hq5Uh8).